# I get a 404 not found error when trying to run a website using flask and apache

Tags: python, apache, flask

I cannot access the flask program through Apache

I've Looked up solutions online to no avail

ServerName http://dockyard.capital
DocumentRoot /home/sean_balbale/DockyardSTT/calling-app

WSGIScriptAlias /Conference /home/sean_balbale/DockyardSTT/calling-app/answer_phone.wsgi
        
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
I should get a username and password field

Comment: share server error log

Comment: Internal Server Error is not a 404, more likely a 500, you probably want to edit the question